# Volume in toroidal coordinates

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I'm asked to determine the volume of a 3d object described with toroidal coordinates. As we never treated this kind of coordinate system before, I'm given the following transformation:

$x = (a+\rho\cos\theta)\cos\phi$

$y = (a+\rho\cos\theta)\sin\phi$

$z = \rho\sin\theta$

The object is described as
$T_{a,b} = \{(\rho,\theta, \phi): 0 \leq \rho \leq b < a,\ 0 \leq \theta \leq 2\pi,\ 0 \leq \phi \leq 2\pi\}$.

First, I need to know the integration factor. I've calculated the determinant of the jacobian matrix. After quite a while, I arrived at an integration factor of $\rho(\sin(\phi)-\cos(\phi))(a+\rho\cos(\theta))$. I can't find anywhere if this answer is correct, but I'm assuming so ofcourse. Now I can calculate the volume:
$V = \int_{\phi=0}^{2\pi} \int_{\theta = 0}^{2\pi} \int_{\rho=0}^b 1\cdot \rho(\sin(\phi)-\cos(\phi))(a+\rho\cos(\theta))\ d\rho\ d\theta\ d\phi$. But, because the geometric functions are periodic with $2\pi$, my result is $V=0$. Looking at the description of $T_{a,b}$, I can't imagine this is the right result, but I can't even get a clear picture of the shape of this object, so I don't know if I should trust my intuition. Could anybody point out the mistake (if there is one of course)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your integration factor is wrong. I calculated the Jacobian of this transformation and got $\rho(a+\rho\cos\theta)$.

That your Jacobian is incorrect can be seen without any computations. Note that the first two rows of the matrix ($x,y$) contain a trigonometric function of $\phi$, while the third does no. So, the determinant will involve an even number of trigonometric $\phi$ factors (possibly zero, since $\cos^2+\sin^2 = 1$).